# Get only the size of a mounted filesystem

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, disk-usage, cut

I want to get only the total size of a mounted filesystem. But the catch is that I only know about the mount point. So, I thought of using the `df` command.

To get the size of this mounted filesystem, I ran the following command:

```
df --output=target,size | grep -w /mnt/xyz
```

The result that I got was something like this:

```
/mnt/xyz             4339044
```

I know how to use `cut` but it was of no use here as the space between the string and the integers is unknown to me. Is there a way to just print this size on the terminal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it without the `grep`:

```
df --output=target,size /mnt/xyz | awk ' NR==2 { print $2 } '
```

`df` accepts as argument the mount point; you can tell to `awk` to print both the second line only (NR==2) , and the 2nd argument, $2.

Or better yet, cut the target as you are not outputting it, and it becomes:

```
df --output=size /mnt/xyz | awk ' NR==2 '
```

When I was a begginer, I also did manage to get around `cut` limitations using `tr -s " "` (squeeze) to cut redundant spaces as in:

```
df --output=target,size /mnt/xyz | tail -1 | tr -s " " | cut -f2 -d" "
```

Comment: df -h /mnt/xyz | awk ' NR==3 ' | awk '{print $1}'

Answer (score 5):

There is also the `findmnt` command, which can print the number of bytes or a "human" number (powers of 1024 with non-iso abbreviations, sadly):

```
$ findmnt -no size /mnt/xyz
 9.7G
$ findmnt -bno size /mnt/xyz
10434699264
```

Comment: Your commands are invalid. Throws error saying that the size column doesn't exist

Comment: my version is 2.26.2. Try `findmnt --help` to see if it lists which columns it allows.